# How to convert K into 1000 and M into 1000000 using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, type-conversion

I have scraped strings from a webpage and placed them into a list.

List1 = ['95.3k', '24.3k', '2.3M','22.1k', '21.6k', '18.2k', '16.2k', '15.7k', '15.5k', '11.2k', '10.2k', '10k', '9.9k', '1.2M', '9.6k', '9.2k', '7.5k', '6.9k', '7.2M', '6.8k', '6.7k', '6.1k', '6k']

I need to remove the 'k' and 'M' and multiply the numbers by 1000 and 1000000 respectively. Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: strip `k` or ignore the last char from each of the strings and convert them to float and multiply them by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

```
List1 = ['95.3k', '24.3k', '2.3M','22.1k', '21.6k', '18.2k', '16.2k', '15.7k', '15.5k', '11.2k', '10.2k', '10k', '9.9k', '1.2M', '9.6k', '9.2k', '7.5k', '6.9k', '7.2M', '6.8k', '6.7k', '6.1k', '6k']
results = []

for item in List1:
    num = float(item[:-1])*(1000 if item[-1].lower() == "k" else 1000000 if item[-1].lower() == "m" else 1)
    results.append(int(num) if int(num) == num else num)

print(results)
```

And the result is:

```
[95300, 24300, 2300000, 22100, 21600, 18200, 16200, 15700, 15500, 11200, 10200, 10000, 9900, 1200000, 9600, 9200, 7500, 6900, 7200000, 6800, 6700, 6100, 6000]
```

Comment: Put the values of your if check in the same case.   When testing, do   `if (item[-1]).lower() == "k"`,   `if (item[-1]).lower() == "m"`

Comment: OK, that's better

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with
`[float(item[:-1])*1000 if item[-1]=='k' else float(item[:-1])*1000000 for item in List1]`

first, we iterate over List1,
then, we strip the `'k'` with `item[:-1]`
then, we convert to float, and last we multiply `*1000`

Comment: You did not check strictly. What if your code is fuzzed? What if your code is neither fed a value with ‘k’ nor ‘M’ at the end?

Answer (score -1):

As forever also mentioned, you can perform this via the following:

```
[str(int(float(j[:-1]) * 1000)) if j[-1] == 'k' else str(int(float(j[:-1]) * 1000000)) for j in List1]
```

Your output would be

```
['95300', '24300', '2300000', '22100', '21600', '18200', '16200', '15700', '15500', '11200', '10200', '10000
', '9900', '1200000', '9600', '9200', '7500', '6900', '7200000', '6800', '6700', '6100', '6000']
```

Here

- `j[:-1]` takes the entire string but the last character, ie, k or M
- It converts the string to a float and then multiplies it by 1000 or 10000000 depending on if the last character is k or not.
- It performs the same on each string in the list via `for j in List1`
- If you would like the decimal points to remain, you can leave it as float as mentioned by forever, or if you would like it to be as an integer use `int`

Comment: Hi there . Please give a working code.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon the code I have provided works....I have executed it python, unless it was an error when I was pasting it.  Edit: I think I fixed the new line issue, do let me know if it's still throwing an error.